# How can you connect a Flex UI to a Unix backend server?

Tags: apache-flex, unix, backend

Im working on a project with the following basic needs:

1. Need to invoke a Flex Webapp in a new Tab from another Webapp in Java/Jsp
2. This Flex UI must be connected to a unix backend to show the backend operations on the UI
3. The unix backend server has telnet operations and SSO

Is this possible? how?

---

Any further help on getting that Java Api

Using it as Adobe Air will require use of a server rite... I wanna do it without any extra server. Just the UI and the backend Unix server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of middleware solution (java based api) that flex can call over the web. Either that or use Flex as a local application (Adobe Air) which can run more OS specific commands

Comment: Any further help on getting that Java Api

Using it as Adobe Air will require use of a server rite... I wanna do it without any extra server. Just the UI and the backend Unix server.

Comment: Can i connect the flex layer to a PHP middle layer and call the unix commands form PHP?? is that possible?

Comment: It's very possible, as long as your apache (or whatever web server that runs php) has the rights to call commands from php.